# Getting "FacebookAds::ClientError (Invalid parameter: Terms of Service Not Accepted (fbtrace_id: Ch/RdwGB+D3))" after i call api to create App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-ads-api, facebook-app-settings

I will explain the scenarios here

1) When user click on link facebook button facebook permission dialog is bypassed and returns back directly on redirect uri(http://localhost:3000/ in my case) with code and state.

2) I am successfully able to exchange the code return above with access token.

3) I used facebooks access token debugger to analyze the token above and shows be proper scopes i need.

[image]

4) After this i fetch ad_accounts id, page token and page ids using this token.
5) when i use this token to create campaign for ads i get the following error.

```
FacebookAds::ClientError (Invalid parameter: Terms of Service Not Accepted (fbtrace_id: Ch/RdwGB+D3))
```

I use ruby [facebook-business-sd](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk)k.

My app is in development mode and not live yet.

I can see both facebook login and marketing api green live in my app dashboard.
[image]

It makes sense to me that i am getting "Terms not accepted error" as user is never prompted to permissions dialog to permit my app for token.

I also observed that if add `scope` params to facebook login uri, the user is prompted to permission dialog.

I must be missing some configuration here, i have not yet submitted my app for review.

Any help/clue is appreciated.

Comment: The user account must visit https://www.facebook.com/ads/leadgen/tos and accept the ToS, before you can make this kind of API call.

Comment: i checked this page and ToS are already accepted and marked with green.

Comment: Specifically for the page(s) in question?

Comment: i can't specifically find them. Api was working fine till friday i was able to create ads.

Comment: i found this https://www.facebook.com/customaudiences/app/tos/ and accepted them

Comment: whats even more annoying is if the api error message throws ToS error it should also share the link of the ToS page like in this case https://github.com/facebook/facebook-nodejs-business-sdk/issues/26

Comment: again i must say fb should consider passing a trace debugger as i can see trace id in the message.